# Non-Linearity Test NaN error

Tags: python, statsmodels

I wanted to try statsmodel's linear_harvey_collier test with an easy example. However, I get nan as a result. Can you see, where my error lies?

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

np.random.seed(44)
n_samples, n_features = 50, 4
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
coef=np.random.uniform(-12,12,4)
y = np.dot(X, coef)
var = 400
y += var**(1/2) * np.random.normal(size=n_samples)
regr=OLS(y, X).fit()
print(regr.params)
print(regr.summary())

sms.linear_harvey_collier(regr)
```

I get the result Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan).

If I perform the test while exluding one variable I get a result:

```py
X3=X[:,:3]
regr3=OLS(y, X3).fit()
In [1]: sms.linear_harvey_collier(regr3)
Out[2]: Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=0.2447803429683807, pvalue=0.806727747845282)
```

Is there a problem with not adding a constant and intercept? This is just a feeling and if there is indeed a problem, I don't understand why.

Comment: I think this belongs in stack overflow rather than CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in linear_harvey_collier, that hard codes the number of initial observations to 3.
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/6727

`linear_harvey_collier` has only two lines of code.
A workaround is to compute the test directly

```
res = regr
from scipy import stats
skip = len(res.params)  # bug in linear_harvey_collier
rr = sms.recursive_olsresiduals(res, skip=skip, alpha=0.95, order_by=None)
stats.ttest_1samp(rr[3][skip:], 0)

Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=0.03092937323130299, pvalue=0.9754626388210277)
```